# Java Servlets - set or alter cookies in included servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Given that we have two servlets A and B and servlet A includes servlet B using

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/B").include(request,response);
```

Why can't I set or alter cookies in servlet B? I don't receive any errors but it seems like the changes on the cookies are being ignored. 
Can anyone explain this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RequestDispatcher.include](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) documentation :

> .....
>
> The ServletResponse object has its path elements and parameters
>   remain unchanged from the caller's. **The included servlet** **cannot change**
>   **the response status code or set headers**; **any attempt to make a change
>   is ignored**.
>
> .....

And since Cookies are part of the returned header (of the calling Servlet), that's why the changes are not taking effect (ignored).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! 
Would be nice though if the servlet container threw a "Header already sent" Exception or something.